Well-posedness result for a linear parabolic equation on torus
Consider the following linear parabolic equation in one spatial dimension for $u=u(x,t)$ on the one-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^1,$ meaning $x \in \mathbb{T}^1$ and $t \in (0, T]:$
$$ \partial_t u- a \cdot\partial_{x}^2u +g(x,t)\cdot u= f(x,t),$$
with the constant $a > 0,$ and the given functions $g,f \geq 0,$ subjected to the strictly positive initial condition $u_0(x) \in C^1(\mathbb{T}^1).$
(For the regularity of $f$ and $g$, I would need $f,g \in L^{\infty}((0, T), L^1(\mathbb{T}^1)),$ but "smoother" assumptions would work too.)
I am looking for a well-posedness result (existence, uniqueness and positivity of the solution in the mild sense) for this equation on the torus. Could someone recommend a literature reference?
I already tried Elliptic and Parabolic Equations. by Z. Wu, J. Yin, and C. Wang, but there are no results on the torus/periodic boundary conditions.
Thanks for help in advance!
